# Kendo grid does not render filter icon in IE8

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

Why Internet Explorer IE8 does not show the filter icon at header column of the Kendo grid? Is it a bug? I checked the code and it set to `filterable:true`. In firefox works.

I use it like that:

```
$("#myHtmlTable1").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 18
    },
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    selectable: true,
    pageable: {
        input: false,
        numeric: false
    },
    change: function () {
        // MY LOGIC
    },
    columns: [
    {
        field: "Col1",
        width: 40
    },
    {
        field: "Col2",
        width: 250
    },
    {
        width: 40,
        field: "Col3"
    },
    {
        width: 150,
        field: "Col4"
    }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` it solves.

Answer (score 1):

Is this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/325/) example working on your side? To me it seems pretty similar to yours.

Comment: I can't see any different. I also have another page in my website and it's shown right.

Comment: You need to reproduce it somehow so we can help you:P